# How to select from an Oracle 11g table called User using HQL

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

In Oracle, if you name a table User, you must query the table by putting quotes around the word user.

This will not work

```
select * from User
```

This will work

```
select * from "User"
```

My question is, how do I run a hibernate HQL query on a table named User?  I have tried putting "" around User, escaping quotes, single quotes, nothing works.  HQL doesn't like those characters and errors out.  I have googled and searched for a solution and found nothing.

Comment: Tip: do not use Oracle Keywords for table or column names. Can you create a stored procedure to return a cursor on the table?

Comment: Yes, it was a moment of headstrong confidence "I will just be able to wrap in quotes later!".  Creating a stored procedure to return a cursor on the table is an interesting idea.  I bet that would work, however I am curious if there are are more straightforward solutions.

Comment: create a synonym for this table having some better name. PS: Oracle tries to be backward compatible and therefore many new keywords still can be used as identifiers. For example you can still name tables "model", 
"join" or "commit".

Comment: That's a great idea I forgot about synonyms!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the table name, in your entity mapping:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="`User`")
public class User {
...
}
```

The when you write an HQL query like this:

```
from User
```

Hibernate will generate an SQL query like this:

```
select * from "User"
```

Comment: Just beware that in this case - when using quotes - "User" and "USER" are two different table names. Quotes also enforce case-sensitivity.